# How to get clicked li values in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this list items

```
<ul id="min-val">
     <li class="__amount" id="__amount" value="5 Lac 
        onclick="selectAmount()">5Lac</li>
     <li class="__amount" value="10 Lac" >10 Lac</li>
     <li class="__amount" value="20 Lac" >20 Lac</li>
     <li class="__amount" value="30 Lac">30 Lac</li>
     </ul>
```

and this is the button where i m calling the below function

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="getResidentType()" >SEARCH</button>
```

and this is javascript function

```
function getResidentType(e){
    var amount__list = document.querySelectorAll('.min__range li');
    amount__list.forEach((item, index) => {
        item.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
         
           console.log(`Min amount is ${event.currentTarget.innerHTML}`);
        });
       
      })
}
```

I need to work like that when I press the search button the clicked li values should display in console.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Showing us only the code that works doesn't help us solve a problem with your code that doesn't work. Show us that code along with a more detailed explanation of what you expect it to do. See [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: 1. you need to place the event listener on submit button.
 2. in your function disable default event
 3. get and display what you want in console
 4. submit form

Comment: If you are submitting the form you might find it easier to just add  a hidden field and update it's value each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to store in a global variable and get value when you click submit button.

```js
var selected = '';
var amount__list = document.querySelectorAll('.min__range li');
amount__list.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        selected = event.currentTarget.innerHTML;
       //console.log(`Min amount is ${event.currentTarget.innerHTML}`);
    });
   
  })
  
function formSubmitted(){
  console.log("selected is ",selected);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onSubmit="return formSubmitted()">
<ul class="min__range">
<li>11</li>
<li>22</li>
<li>33</li>
</ul>
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```